# ADC Calibration Method

Tags: c++, c, calibration, adc

I'm using a MOD54415 NetBurner Module to drive a SPI controlled, 16 input, 12 bit ADC (AD7490B) but I'm noticing a >0.3% error in the readback - I sample 10.000 volts, I get a reading of 9.9645 volts back. I'm trying to write a calibration routine for it to close that error to 0.1% or better, but I'm really not sure how to proceed. I have done quadratic curve matching in Excel with a plot of the data input and data read from the ADC, but I'm not sure if that's the best way to implement it, how many cycles the floating point math will consume, and if there's a better way. Overall, I've never had to do any kind of calibration before, so I'm not really sure where to start. Can someone point me in the right direction? If it helps, the processor is 250MHz, and I poll all 16 channels every 0.1 seconds (SPI speed is 20MHz). Thanks all!

Edit: The inputs are actually only 5V tolerant. I have a follower buffer, and a 2:1 divider filter. I provided 5.000 and 10.000 from a reference source, and measured it with a DMM that reads 4 decimal places. A the input pin of the ADC, I read 5.0009V and 2.5005, and the ADC should be reading 0xFFF (+/- 2LSB) but it's reading 0xFEC to 0xFF3 (approximate). I just did the math to calculate the numbers.

Comment: How are you sure that it's actually 10v? Is there a possibility that the measuring device you're using has its own potential difference?

Comment: Doesn't 10V exceed the max ratings for the ADC?  How are you scaling your input and reference voltages?

Comment: You should be able to compensate for some gain error by adjusting the voltage divider ratio at the input...

Comment: If you already have a calibration curve for each equipment, I can't see what more you can do in software.  Production testing and conformance are procedural and contractual matters that are outside the scope of SO.

Comment: @Dmitri The divider ratio is pre set to be exact and precise as possible. the divider uses 0.1% resistors and a 5% cap. This was spec given to me. It has to be done in software.

Comment: @MartinJames I made the calibration curve in excel for one ADC input only just to see a curve in general. I could characterize the whole device, but I'm not sure of the best/most efficient.industry standard methos of calibration.